EXC_BAD_ACCESS, KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS, lookUpImpOrForward + 100
My Swift app is crashing SOMETIMES while launching. The stacktrace is giving me a bad access error from native code. There are lots of similar KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS exceptions in swift or objective C applications. But my error is specifically caused by "lookUpImpOrForward + 100". I have added the stacktrace below. It starts with my appdelegate, but not inside a method. So the native ios codes are unable to launch my app sometimes. It doesn't happen always. A similar question is asked 5 years ago here but there is no answer to that either. Also, that question is caused by a different line and a very old system. Here is my appdelegate:
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import GoogleMobileAds

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate
{
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
    {
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(google_maps_key)
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        set_strings()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
        {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        }
        else
        {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)
    {
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)
    {
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)
    {
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)
    {
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)
    {
    }
}

AND here is the stacktrace:
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x4e3c lookUpImpOrForward + 100
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x34c4 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
2  UIKitCore                      0x67e8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) subviews] + 104
3  UIKitCore                      0x660c -[UIView(MultiLayer) _allSubviews] + 112
4  UIKitCore                      0x65d20 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 440
5  UIKitCore                      0x65d80 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 536
6  UIKitCore                      0x65d80 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 536
7  UIKitCore                      0x65d80 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 536
8  CoreAutoLayout                 0x11f14 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 84
9  UIKitCore                      0x9c164 __100-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke + 124
10 UIKitCore                      0x9aa9c -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 112
11 UIKitCore                      0x99ad0 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 172
12 UIKitCore                      0x5bab4 -[UIView _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 388
13 UIKitCore                      0x5b648 -[UIView _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 324
14 UIKitCore                      0x5b3d0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutSubviews] + 192
15 UIKitCore                      0xe9f044 -[UIPickerView layoutSubviews] + 236
16 UIKitCore                      0xea0738 -[UIPickerView selectedRowInComponent:] + 64
17 UIKitCore                      0xe9dcc4 -[UIPickerView _updateSelectedRows] + 100
18 UIKitCore                      0xe9dd54 -[UIPickerView didMoveToWindow] + 84
19 UIKitCore                      0x29aa0 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1716
20 UIKitCore                      0x29698 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 684
21 UIKitCore                      0x29698 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 684
22 UIKitCore                      0x29698 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 684
23 UIKitCore                      0x29698 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 684
24 UIKitCore                      0x29698 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 684
25 UIKitCore                      0x29698 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 684
26 UIKitCore                      0x1aa70 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 124
27 CoreAutoLayout                 0x11f14 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 84
28 UIKitCore                      0x1d914 -[UIView _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 504
29 UIKitCore                      0x1c3d0 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 2200
30 UIKitCore                      0x3b50ec -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 868
31 UIKitCore                      0x313a80 -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:] + 1300
32 UIKitCore                      0x46c6f0 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke_3 + 52
33 UIKitCore                      0x46c564 +[UIKeyboardSceneDelegate _pinInputViewsForKeyboardSceneDelegate:onBehalfOfResponder:duringBlock:] + 96
34 UIKitCore                      0x46c4c8 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke_2 + 196
35 UIKitCore                      0x46c26c +[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:] + 180
36 UIKitCore                      0x3134d0 _UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition + 484
37 UIKitCore                      0x310b38 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_3 + 1584
38 UIKitCore                      0xba6e4 -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 72
39 UIKitCore                      0xba5a8 -[_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush] + 164
40 UIKitCore                      0xba4c0 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 496
41 UIKitCore                      0xba0f8 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 80
42 UIKitCore                      0xba008 _UIApplicationFlushCATransaction + 72
43 UIKitCore                      0xb776c _UIUpdateSequenceRun + 84
44 UIKitCore                      0xb73b0 schedulerStepScheduledMainSection + 172
45 UIKitCore                      0xb8254 runloopSourceCallback + 92
46 CoreFoundation                 0x56834 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
47 CoreFoundation                 0x567c8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
48 CoreFoundation                 0x54298 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
49 CoreFoundation                 0x53484 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
50 CoreFoundation                 0x52cd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
51 GraphicsServices               0x11a8 GSEventRunModal + 164
52 UIKitCore                      0x40a90c -[UIApplication _run] + 888
53 UIKitCore                      0x4be9d0 UIApplicationMain + 340
54 WhoShares                      0x6f544 main + 9 (AppDelegate.swift:9)

Why could this happen? It is not even in my code. Thanks in advance.
